# How to use string of object to instantiate object

Tags: java, oop

In JAVA, say I have a string variable:

```
String x = "CoolClass";
```

And I have a class called CoolClass with a working constructor. How could I create an object of CoolClass, using the variable x, instead of typing CoolClass itself.

(I need to do this because x will be given by the user and read in by Scanner, and depending on their input, a different object/class will be constructed accordingly).

Comment: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is a good place to start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Class.forName(x).newInstance()
```

would work, though reflection can be tricky and dangerous.  Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Sure Louis! I have different classes for different animals. I ask the user to input one type of animal. I scan their response, and save it as a string. Then, I create an object (animal) of that string. Would your suggestion be "dangerous" for that purpose?

Comment: I would generally prefer to have an explicit list, or even better, a `Map<String, AnimalFactory>`.  This'll work, though.

Answer (score 6):

This task requires reflection -- `Class.forName(x).newInstance()`. 
You might want to use a different design method. Why is the user typing in the desired class?

Comment: It is a simulation of a zoo, and they create different animals for different cages. It is a game, nothing serious :o)

Comment: @StellaJ A better design pattern might be to use an overarching `Animal` class, then have the user input the type and store it as a local variable. Creating different classes for different animals seems like overkill, especially since you'll need to call the same methods on all of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.In)
String animalType = kbReader.nextLine();

Animal animal; //assume that Lion, Tiger, and Bear inherit Animal

if(animalType.equals("Lion")
{
   animal = new Lion();
}

else if(animalType.equals("Tiger")
{
   animal = new Tiger();
}

else if(animalType.equals("Bear")
{
   animal = new Bear();
}
```

This is without using reflection of any sort.

Comment: Thank you, I might use that to be safe :o)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Class.forName(x).newInstance()` if your class has default constructor. If the constructor is expected to receive parameters use `Class.forName(x).getConstructor(YOUR PARAMETER TYPES).newInstance(YOUR ARGUMENTS)`